# How to show home tableview only selected index item array count in next viewcontroll tableview in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, uitableview

I have home collectionView, here if i click one item using didSelectItemAtindexPathin in home that item values array need to show in AllMakePaymentViewController tableview. 
but here i am getting all home items values in AllMakePaymentViewController... but how to show only clicked item values in AllMakePaymentViewController tableview.
for that same typename have in both home and AllMakePaymentViewController json..
Please help me in the code.

here is my code for homeVC:

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage
struct JsonData {
var iconHome: String?
var typeName: String?
var id: String?
init(icon: String, tpe: String, id: String) {
    self.iconHome = icon
    self.typeName = tpe
    self.id = id
}
}
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var itemsArray = [JsonData]()
var typeName: String?
var saveTypenameKey: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    homeServiceCall()
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemsArray.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell

    let aData = itemsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.paymentLabel.text = aData.typeName
    cell.paymentImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:aData.iconHome ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "varun finance5_icon"))
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if itemsArray[indexPath.item].typeName == "WATER"{
        let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AllMakePaymentViewController") as? AllMakePaymentViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController!, animated: true)
    }
    else if itemsArray[indexPath.item].typeName == "ELECTRICITY"{
        let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AllMakePaymentViewController") as? AllMakePaymentViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController!, animated: true)
    }
    else if itemsArray[indexPath.item].typeName == "CASH POINT"{
        let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AllMakePaymentViewController") as? AllMakePaymentViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController!, animated: true)
    }
    else if itemsArray[indexPath.item].typeName == "DTH"{
        let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AllMakePaymentViewController") as? AllMakePaymentViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController!, animated: true)
    }
    else{
        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "will update soon..", in: self)
    }
}
//MARK:- Service-call
func homeServiceCall(){

    let urlStr = "https://dev.com/webservices/getfinancer"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        guard let respData = data else {
            return
        }
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        do{
            let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: respData, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
            //print("the home json is \(jsonObj)")
            let financerArray = jsonObj["financer"] as! [[String: Any]]

            for financer in financerArray {
                let id = financer["id"] as? String
                let pic = financer["icon"] as? String
                self.typeName = financer["tpe"] as! String
                KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.typeName!, forKey: "typeName")
                print("keychain typename \(KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.typeName!, forKey: "typeName"))")
                self.itemsArray.append(JsonData(icon: pic ?? "", tpe: self.typeName ?? "", id: id ?? ""))
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("catch error")
        }
    }).resume()
}
}
```

**This is my AllMakePaymentViewController code:**

```
class PaymentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
@IBOutlet weak var pamntTypeLabel: UILabel!
}

class AllMakePaymentViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var categoryName: String?
var iteamsArray = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    allPaymentService()
}
func allPaymentService(){

    let urlStr = "https://dev.com/webservices/api.php?rquest=billermdm"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        guard let respData = data else {
            return
        }
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        do{
            let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: respData, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
            //print("the all make payment json is \(jsonObj)")
            let billerdetailsArray = jsonObj["billerdetails"] as! [[String: Any]]

            for billerdetail in billerdetailsArray {

                self.categoryName = billerdetail["bcategoryname"] as? String

                if self.categoryName == "Water"{
                    let bName = billerdetail["bname"] as? String
                    self.iteamsArray.append(bName ?? "")
                }
                if self.categoryName == "Electricity"{
                    let bName = billerdetail["bname"] as? String
                    self.iteamsArray.append(bName ?? "")
                }
                if self.categoryName == "CashPoin"{
                    let bName = billerdetail["bname"] as? String
                    self.iteamsArray.append(bName ?? "")
                }
                if self.categoryName == "DTH"{
                    let bName = billerdetail["bname"] as? String
                    self.iteamsArray.append(bName ?? "")
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("catch error")
        }
    }).resume()
}
}

extension AllMakePaymentViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if categoryName == "Water"{
        return iteamsArray.count
    }
    if categoryName == "Landline Postpaid"{
        return iteamsArray.count
    }
    if categoryName == "DTH"{
        return iteamsArray.count
    }
    if categoryName == "Electricity"{
        return iteamsArray.count
    }
    return iteamsArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! PaymentTableViewCell
    cell.pamntTypeLabel.text = iteamsArray[indexPath.row]
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    return cell
}
}
```

here only one itemsArray is enough or shall i take diierent array fro different category like electrictyArray, waterArray... because here i am getting all values in tabelview... i need only clicked home item valuesarray..
Please help me in the code

Comment: anyone want to help i will share code using github for better understand.. please help in the code

Comment: Could you recap and tell me what is exactly your issue and what is your expected result from your code?

Comment: @jacob, if i do like above code, if i click any item from home `didSelectItemAt` i mean if i click water or electricity i am getting all categoryName(water, electricity,dth.. )in tableview because i am appending all values to singlearray (`iteamsArray`).

Comment: @jacob, actually i need is, if i click water in home i want only water category values in AllMakePaymentViewController tableview, and if i click dth then only dth related stuff.... like for all home items

Comment: To be clear, the home page show all the category. Then if i click on any item in the home page then come to AllMakePaymentViewController, then what should be showed in that controller?

Comment: @jacob if u click WATER item in home then u will get water values in if self.categoryName == "Water"{
                    let bName = billerdetail["bname"] as? String
                    self.iteamsArray.append(bName ?? "")
                }   in AllMakePaymentViewController and need to show in tableview..

Comment: @jacob in the same way if click any item in hoem u need to disply that item related values in allmakpameVC..... in github code once u click last item and uncomment DTH if condition..u can see DTH values in tableview

Comment: sorry i didn't shared posted code because.. i dont't want multiple if conditions...

Comment: if mutiple `if conditions` need please go with it, altimately i need code to be work

Comment: Seems i dont have enough information to help you resolve this issue @iosSwift. And sorry for late response, mate

Comment: @jacob yeah true without enough information its really difficult to understand `allPaymentService()` api response.. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the var in `nextViewController` before pushing it onto the stack (and you should use `if let` to avoid potential crashes):

```
    if let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AllMakePaymentViewController") as? AllMakePaymentViewController {
        // set the var in the new view controller
        nextViewController.categoryName = "WATER"
        // now push it onto the stack
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
    }
```